# undefined method `user?' in rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using devise gem. My project's purpose user can upload files & delete thier own file but not other user's file. So, I write "user?" method for ensure that correct user can only show the delete button. I also ensure the 'correct_user' method for delete file. but now I'm faceing this problem "NoMethodError at /upload_files.."
"undefined method `user?' "

Here is my **upload_files_controller.rb** file:

```
class UploadFilesController < ApplicationController

  before_action :logged_in
  before_action :correct_user,   only: :destroy

  def index
    @upload_files = UploadFile.all
  end

  def new
    @upload_file = UploadFile.new
  end


  def create
    @upload_file = current_user.upload_files.build(upload_params)


    if @upload_file.save
      redirect_to upload_files_path, notice: "The file #{@upload_file.name} has been uploaded."
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    upload_file = UploadFile.find(params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to upload_files_path, notice:  "The file #{upload_file.name} has been deleted."
  end



  def user?(check_user)
    check_user == current_user.id
  end




  private
  def upload_params
    params.require(:upload_file).permit(:name, :upload_file)
  end


  def logged_in
    if admin_signed_in?
      return true
    else
      authenticate_user!
    end
  end


  def correct_user
    @upload_file = current_user.upload_files.find_by(id: params[:id])
    redirect_to root_url if @upload_file.nil?
  end

end
```

Here is my **upload_files/index.html.erb** file:

```
  <% @upload_files.each do |file| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= file.name %></td>
        <td><%= link_to "Download File", file.file_name_url %></td>


        <%if admin_signed_in? %>

            <td><%= button_to "Delete",  file, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", confirm: "Are you sure that you wish to delete #{file.name}?" %></td>

        <% else user?(file.user_id) %>

            <td><%= button_to "Delete",  file, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", confirm: "Are you sure that you wish to delete #{file.name}?" %></td>

        <% end %>


      </tr>
  <% end %>
```

what did I wrong? please show me a way.

Thanks,
Mezbah

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place your `user?` method in helper.

About your view code, why don't you use boolean alternative?

```
<% if admin_signed_in? || user?(file.user_id) %>
  <td><%= button_to "Delete",  file, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", confirm: "Are you sure that you wish to delete #{file.name}?" %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks. its working. But still I have one problem. "delete button is seen for all user". i want it hidden for who are not correct user.

Comment: @Mezbah it should work now. Your approach was very strange BTW.

Answer (score 2):

`Marek` is right, however, you may wish to use an [authorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authorization) gem such as [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) for this

There's a great [Railscast about authorization here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan):

[image]

To give you a brief synopsis, **authorization** is the authority that a user has to CRUD an object. Authentication (Devise) is for giving the user "permission" to use various features in the application; authorization is allowing the user to edit / change data depending on their level of access

Your choice of trying to add a button so that users will be able to remove their own object. This is perfect `CanCanCan` territory:

--

**CanCanCan**

This gem was originally called "[CanCan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan)", but as Ryan Bates has gone on leave, some of the Rails community took it upon themselves to make their own gem, calling it CanCanCan

The way it works is relatively simple:

> 1. Have an "ability" model to define user abilities
> 2. Call the `can?` method to determine if a user can partake in a particular action

This means that you'll be able to make an extensible piece of functionality which will grant your users access to specific objects as required. Here's how:

```
> rails g cancan:ability
```

This will create the `ability` model to define all the methods:

```
#app/models/ability.rb
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, :all
    end
  end
end
```

This will give you the ability to then call the `can?` method on your various objects:

```
<td>
  <% if admin_signed_in? || (can? :destroy, file) %>
    <%= button_to "Delete",  file, method: :delete, class: "btn btn-danger", confirm: "Are you sure that you wish to delete #{file.name}?" %>
  <% end %>
</td>
```

Comment: If you want me to define the abilities for you, I'll refactor the code. I didn't mean this to replace `Marek`'s answer, just add to it

Comment: in my project i have two separate model one for user & another for admin. For this previously i got some problem. Will you please show me a way? how can i define abilities for both model?

Answer (score 1):

I would add the following method to your `application_controller.rb`. That makes that method available in all controllers and views within your application.

```
# application_controller.rb
def current_user?(user)
  current_user == user
end
helper_method :current_user?
```

Use that method like this in your view:

```
# in view
<% if admin_signed_in? || current_user?(file.user) %>
  <td>
    <%= button_to('Delete', file, 
                   method:  :delete, 
                   class:   'btn btn-danger', 
                   confirm: "Are you sure that you wish to delete #{file.name}?") %>
  </td>
<% end %>
```